# "Окочуриться"

Tags: этимология

А какая этимология слова "окочуриться"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общеизвестных этимологических словарях этого слова попросту нет. Думаю, дело в том, что оно необщеупотребительное, имеет явную разговорную окраску. Это подтверждает и словарь Даля, где слово числится диалектным. Но в толковом словаре Шведовой есть вот такие сведения. ОКОЧУРИТЬСЯ -  Из *о-кочуриться*, ср. диал. *кочуриться, качуриться* ‘находиться при смерти, умирать’, производн. от диал. *кочёра* ‘кривая ёлка; обрубок суковатого дерева’, *кочура* ‘кочка’, одного корня со словами *кочан, кочка*; ср. кол ~ околеть. Слово *кочан* в славянских языках очевидно связано с твёрдостью (кочан - кочерыжка). Поэтому коченеть - становиться твёрдым (как кочерыжка), а окочуриться - экспрессивная форма "окоченеть". 
Все, что связано со смертью, человек старается не называть прямо. У слова "умереть" около 80 синонимов. *Окочуриться* - один из них. На ум тут же приходит гробовых дел мастер Безенчук из "12 стульев" ;-)

Answer (score 4):

ОкоЧУРиться происходит от славянского "чур" - низший бог представляющий всех предков семьи. Изображался в виде "чура" или "чурки" (обработанного бруска, с вырезанным лицом предка) и обычно устанавливался в красном углу. Отсюда "окочуриться" - значит стать Чуром, уйти в мир предков.

Comment: Это правдоподобная версия, но хотелось бы ссылку.